# Is there a "standard" way of organize/boostrap an Express.js server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm pretty new to Node.js and the JavaScript world, coming from a PHP environment.

I'm facing the following issue: many PHP frameworks do the "heavy" stuff of boostrapping the application (i.e. setup the server, middlwares, logger, conguration) on their own.

In Express, I'm doing it "manually" in a single `app.ts` (TypeScript example):

```
// Create schema and load configurations
import config from './config';

// Configure and load the logger
import logger from './logger';

// Create the Express.js server
// ...

// Configure global middlewares
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(compression());
app.use('/', express.static(`${__dirname}/../public`));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Configure global routing
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/../public/index.html`);
});

// Establish a connection to the database server
createConnection({
  // options
}).then(() => {    
  // Start the web server
  app.listen(/* options */);
});
```

This file (here is a portion) become too big, I'd like to split it. Is there any "standard" way of doing it in the Node ecosystem?

Does the following approach make sense?

```
import * as express from 'express';
import config from './config';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

export class ServerConfigurer {
  configureApp(app): void {
    // Configure global middlewares
  }
  createConnection(): Promise<Connection> {
    // Create MySQL connection
  }
}
```

... then in my `app.ts` use `ServerConfigurer` class to boostrap the application.

Comment: There is no "standard" way.  I would say that the most common way I've seen is to initialize the server and all global middleware in one file and then put route definitions in other files that export a router.  You can then import them and activate them each with a single line `app.use("/somepath", require("./someRoutes.js"));` statement.  I haven't really seen a need to create a `serverConfigurer` class because it's largely stuff that is just used once in one place in the code.  Usually, if you move the route definitions out of the server init file, then it won't be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Express, I'm doing it "manually" in a single `app.ts`

That is the case with practically any microframework and particularly so with Express. There is no right or wrong way to organize your project.

> Is there a “standard” way of organize/boostrap an Express.js server?

*Typically*, many examples you will find follow the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. For example, you will typically find the layout as so:

```
example
├── app.js
├── controllers/
├── models/
├── routes/
├── public/
└── views/
```

However, Express is primarily used to build APIs. Nowadays the frontend (`views/` and `public/` folder) is *typically* a React, Vue, or Angular application that is its own project, **separate** from your Express API. With that said, an *typical* Express API project layout would be:

```
example
├── app.js
├── controllers/
├── models/
└── routes/
```

`app.js` is where all the initialization of anything and everything takes place. By initialization, I mean mounting the routes, middleware, database connection, event listeners...anything really. `app.js` is the main/first entry point of your Express app.

`models/` is where you would define all your database models (*typically* Mongo). For example:

```
// models/contact.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const definition = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  }
};

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(definition, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', schema);
```

`controllers/` is where all your route handlers would go. For example:

```
// controllers/contact.js
const Contact = require('../models/contact');

exports.index = async (req, res) => {
  const contacts = await Contact.find().exec();
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    data: contacts,
  });
};
```

Finally we have `routes/` which is where you define all your routes and mount/map the controllers. For example:

```
// routes/contact.js
const express = require('express');
const contactController = require('../controllers/contact');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', contactController.index);

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, we need to connect everything together:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const contactRoutes = require('./routes/contact');

const app = express();

// Connect to mongo.
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

// Fail on connection error since we need the database.
mongoose.connection.on('error', error => { throw error; });

// Allows parsing the body content via `req.body`
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// Mount API routes.
app.use('/contacts', contactRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.NODE_PORT}`))
```

Comment: Excellent, great explanation. Yes, I'm concerted only about `app.ts` because my controllers and models are already in a separate folder, then loaded in `app.ts`. So it's quite common to "glue" modules togheter in `app.ts`?

Comment: Only the top most modules, meaning global stuff such as middleware that applies to _all_ routes. You can see in my example, I only import my `Contact` model in the controller. There's no need to import it in the main `app` file.